# OpenSSL failed to allocate memory (NoMemoryError)

Tags: ruby, encryption, openssl, aes

I am trying to decrypt a encrypted file. The encrypted file size is 0.97 GB. The decryption works perfectly fine for less  size files.

Please find the code i have for decryption.

```
def do_encrypt
  encrypted_file = File.new(output_file, 'wb')
  encrypted_output = encrypt(File.open(file, 'rb'))
  encrypted_file.write(encrypted_output)
  encrypted_file.close
end

def decrypt(io)
  aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("AES-256-CBC")
  aes.decrypt
  aes.key = "cryptoKeyString"
  aes.iv = "ivString"
  aes.update(io.read) + aes.final # code is breaking here
end
```

I have sufficient RAM memory in system over 4GB free. I am getting following error logged on console.

```
encrypt_decrypt.rb:80:in `update': failed to allocate memory (NoMemoryError)
from encrypt_decrypt.rb:80:in `decrypt'
from encrypt_decrypt.rb:62:in `do_decrypt'
from encrypt_decrypt.rb:47:in `run'
from encrypt_decrypt.rb:85:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Well? Don't read it all in then, use multiple calls to `aes.update()`. Sheesh.

Comment: @Maarten what I should do exactly? How to do multiple calls to aes.update() ?

Comment: 1. create a buffer 2. read into the buffer 3. perform multiple calls to update 4. write the result to output stream.